# String on stack when manipulating pointer

Tags: c

Consider this code:

```
char* f(char* str)
{
    return ++str;
}

int main()
{
    char* str = "test";
    str = f(str);
    //flag
    return 0;
}
```

At 'flag' what happens with the memory address where the first original 't' resides? Will it be free-ed or will it be a 'stack leak'?

Comment: `char* str = "test";` allocate the string in the read only memory. Only the pointer `str` is allocated on stack, and its value is updated from the call to the function `f()`. No stack change happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *str = "test";
```

There are 2 objects "in play" here: the `str` object of type `char*` (pointer to char) and the unnamed object of type `char[5]`.

The unnamed array object (with contents `{'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0}`), when used as initialization value for a pointer get converted to a pointer to its first element and it's that address that gets copied to `str`.

There is no allocation of memory, so there is no chance of having memory leaking!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I declared it explicitly like this char str[5] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0}

Comment: Still no allocation. `str` is associated with an area of memory 5-bytes long but the management of that area is done automatically by the implementation; the programmer does not need to think about it -- it gets automagically created when the statement "is executed" and gets automagically destroyed when the encompassing `}` is reached.

Comment: ok but this could be a problem then right? if you did this with large data sets at the beginning of some high level function. Or main?

Comment: Yes, it could cause issues. For large objects it's better to use `malloc()` and friends. For example: `int main(void) { char giga[1024*1024*1024]; }` will probably fail in contrast with `int main(void) { char *giga = malloc(1024*1024*1024); frre(giga); }`

Answer (score 2):

The string literal `"test"` will be welded into the executable, and the OS will place it in read-only memory (that's why attempts to modify string literals often trigger a segmentation fault) while loading the file. The OS is also responsible for properly unloading the data.

So, that data is *not* placed on the stack, but `char* str` is. Since it's a regular local variable, it'll be deallocated automatically by the code inserted by the compiler.

To answer the question: at `//flag` the whole content of `"test"` will still be present at the same address initially allocated by the OS, and the stack won't be involved here at all. While processing the `return` statement, the compiler will insert code to clean up the stack.

Comment: Ok thanks, what if I declared it like this: char str[5]; strcopy(str, "test");

Comment: @Lythoc, doesn't matter: the literal `"test"` will always be embedded into your executable and later stored in read-only memory by the OS.

Comment: Ok thanks again. :) Final question, is there a danger then to have 'leaks' in read-only memory? Does the OS ever do a garbage collection pass on it during runtime?

Comment: There is no requirement to place string literals in read-only memory. Implementations are free to place the array wherever they like best :)

Comment: @Lythoc, literals are part of the executable (because they're not supposed to be changed, like your program's bytecode), and are loaded and offloaded along with it. The OS cannot do garbage collection because it has no way of knowing if that data will ever be used again or not _while the program is still running_. Once it has finished execution, the OS has to offload _the whole executable_, and so all the constants will be gone too

Comment: @ForceBru just to clear my understanding. After char str[5]; strcopy(str, "test") now {'t', 'e', 's', 't', 0} is both on the stack and read only memory right? So at //flag in my code that first 't' on the stack is still wasted?

Comment: @Lythoc, no, nothing is wasted. The code inserted by the compiler will automatically take care of that. The thing is, the memory allocated for the variable `str` is different from the address stored in `str`, so, when you increase `str` with `++str`, the address stored in `str` will change, but not the memory location of `str`. The compiler only cares about the latter, so it will automatically insert code to clean it up.

Comment: @ForceBru RIght, is that defined behavior in the standard though? Or does it differ per compiler. Anyway I take your word for it. Thanks for your patience! As a side note, stackoverflow is great but this format of commenting on answers is not ideal.. I'd think the nature of programming questions would inspire or more discussion/follow up friendly format...

Comment: @Lythoc, I'm relatively sure the standard doesn't allow leaking _compile-time constants_ as that would be a pretty odd thing to do anyway

Comment: @lythoc: the phrase "allocated on the stack" is an imprecise way of saying "allocated automatically", which is what the standard defines. The lifetime of an automatically allocated object terminates when control flow exits the block in which the object was automatically allocated. The most common implementation of that is fir the compiler to emit code which bumps a stack pointer on entry to the block, and restores the stack pointer on exit. But the standard doesn't prescribe mechanisms, only observable outcomes. (1/2)

Comment: @rici That's what I understand but the essence of my question was what happens if there are elements of a datastructure on the stack that are not logical reachable.

Comment: "Automatic allocation" is automatic in the sense that the implementation takes care of all the details. The program itself has no mechanism to interfere, and must trust the implementation (as with anything else, such as correctly multiplying two numbers). The standard does not actually constrain the implementation to recycle automatically allocated memory at a precise moment; the implementation could recycle the memory early if it can prove that the memory won't be referenced again during its lifetime, or it could defer until a more convenient moment. But it will do it.

Comment: @lythoc: the memory is not reachable by the program, but that doesn't mean it's not reachable by the implementation. The implementation must have some mechanism (such as a saved stack pointer) which allows it to manage automatically allocated memory. You cannot fool it unless you do something with undefined behaviour. Incrementing a valid pointer is well defined.

Comment: Or to put it more simply, the stack has no holes. When you pop the stack back to some previous level, everything beyond that is gone.

Comment: @rici ok thanks I think I understand. And like the other answerer mentioned, if we're dealing with data sizes where it potentially could strain the stack we should use the heap anyway. For things like trimming a string where a few chars on stack are unused for the lifetime of a function it doesn't matter it all.

Comment: @lythoc: ignore the array part. When you place `int i, j;` inside a function, you're telling the compiler to automatically allocate space for them. It is irrelevant whether you ever look at addresses of these variables. The lifetime of the variables ends when the function returns and the compiler will arrange for the memory to be reusable. An array allocated on the stack is no different. But note: `char* foo;` only automatically allocates the pointer value `foo`. The object it points at is a completely different matter.